# How to resolve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next' in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file where the odd lines are department numbers, and even ones are sales totals.  I need to be able to read a line and append it to a variable to be used later.

```
def main():
    with open('P2data.txt') as x:
        data = x.readlines()    
        dept = (data)[::2]    
        sales = (data)[1::2]   
    if dept == '1':
        total = sales.next()
        total.append(total1)
    elif dept == '2':
        total = sales.next()
        total.append(total2)
    else:
        total = sales.next()
        total.append(total3)
    print('Dept 1:', total1)
    print('Dept 2:', total2)
    print('Dept 3:', total3)
main()
```

Comment: Above is the code that I am using.  I just keep getting the error message AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: What did you expect `sales.next()` to do? And where do you expect `total1`, `total2`, or `total3` to come from?

Comment: What I was expecting was that sales.next() would read the next line, then append it to the total1.

Comment: What's happening is that `next()` is a generator method and generators are typically written using parentheses. `data` is a list but the author thinks (and maybe it's valid in some situations?) that adding parentheses around a list turns it into a generator; enabling the use of `next()`

Comment: `dept` is a list of strings. How could it be equal to a string?

Comment: I am trying to find "1" within dept.  So, if the first line is equal to "1", then I want to read the next line and append it to total1.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Basically, all of the odd numbered lines are department numbers, and the even ones are sales totals.  So, I am trying to do an if/else statement to read the department numbers and then add up their associated sales totals.

Comment: Okay, I inserted sales = (x for x in sales).  I am now getting AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'.

Comment: Note how you are only checking the department one time. You might want some kind of loop.

Comment: Would a while readline(): work in this instance?

Comment: I've done that, but I am still getting the AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next' error

Comment: @LinzG I suspect you're after something else than your question title suggests. Should it actually be called *"How do I read every second line of a text file and store certain section of the line as variables"* or something along those lines? Seeing a snippet of your input data and your desired output would make it easy to fix.

Comment: Here, below is a sample of the file that I am reading from (the first line is the dept # and the second is the sales total).  The objective is to read the file, if it is dept 1, append the following sales total to total1, if it is dept 2 to append the line to total2 and so on                                                          1
50.30
2
35.14
1
10.16

Comment: You don't even need any of this `next()` business. There's no loop in your program to check each department's values. How familiar are you with `while` or `for` loops?

Comment: @LinzG Ok. As TigerhawkT3 says, you don't need to explicitly call next and make your own generators. Check if the file reading method I've posted in an answer is more intuitive. It reads one line at a time from the top and prints the line number, "even" or "odd" and the line contents. However, looking at even/odd lines might not be what you want because it seems like you have actual, written numbers in the file (1 and 2) that you need to parse to figure out where to put the data in the *following* line

Answer (score 1):

Your code is going in the wrong direction. You also are doing things like checking an entire data structure against what should be compared to one of that structure's elements, and mixing up the syntax for appending to a list. Simply loop over the data structures you create and add to a dictionary:

```
def main():
    with open('P2data.txt') as x:
        data = [line.strip() for line in x]
    dept = data[::2]
    sales = data[1::2]
    totals = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0}
    for dep,sale in zip(dept, sales):
        totals[dep] += float(sale)
    for dep in sorted(totals):
        print('Dept {}: {}'.format(dep, totals[dep]))

main()
```

Comment: `print('Dept {}: {}'.format(dep, totals[dep]))`, right?

Comment: @jDo - `dep`? More like `derp`, tonight. Thanks. :P